# Node.js + Arangodb to make a connection and get a query

Tags: node.js, arangodb

I am new to backend service. I have been trying to make a connection to arangodb from node server. I have a created a basic query in arangodb. the user auth in arangodb is so complicated and there are very few tutorials for node and arangadb combo. I have posted my code below. I have found this example online.

```
DataService.js

var arangojs = require('arangojs');

// Const variables for connecting to ArangoDB database

const host = '192.100.00.000'
const port = '8529'
const username = 'abcde'
const password = 'abcde'
const path = '/_db/_system/_api/'
const databasename = 'xyzm_app'

// Connection to ArangoDB
var db = new arangojs.Database({
url: `http://${host}:${port}${path}${databasename}`,
databaseName: databasename
});

 db.useBasicAuth(username, password);
//console.log(db);

module.exports = {
getAllControllers : function(){
     return db.query('For x IN {user_details} RETURN NEW {
id: x._user_details/7977010,
name: x.char_ctrl_username,
email:x.char_ctrl_email
}')
    .then(cursor => {
        return cursor.all()

 });
}
```

query in db

[image]

Comment: I don't see any obvious mistakes. Is something not working? Do you get an Error? Please update your post with more details

Comment: @Lukilas hallo..,there is no connection established. I have been tracking the ip with wireshark and there isno flow at all

Comment: do you have access to the web interface? should be 192.100.0.0:8529/_db/_system/_admin/aardvark/index.html

Comment: I think you don't need the path part, since arangojs automatically appends the correct path if you specify the database name. Try this: var db = new arangojs.Database({ url: `http://${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}`, databaseName: databasename});

Comment: @Lukilas yes, i have the access to it.

Comment: @Lukilas you have the answer there, basically, do not include the databaseName and the path in the url since you are passing in databaseName as a property separately

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the arangojs [README](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/blob/master/README.md#basic-usage-example):

```
// Or using a fully qualified URL containing the database path
const db = new Database({
  url: `http://${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}/_db/${database}`,
  databaseName: false // don't automatically append database path to URL
});
```

> - databaseName: string (Default: _system)
>
>   Name of the active database.
>
>   If this option is explicitly set to false, the url is expected to contain the database path and the useDatabase method can not be used to switch databases.

So you either specify the full path like `http://host:port/_db/dbname` and set `databaseName: false`, or you use `http://host:port` and either specify `databaseName: "dbname"` or `useDatabase("dbname")`.

`/_api` should not be part of the path, ever. arangojs knows where to find the API endpoint and does it for you.

```
var arangojs = require('arangojs');

// Const variables for connecting to ArangoDB database
const host = '127.0.0.1'
const port = '8529'
const username = 'xyz'
const password = 'xyz'
const databasename = 'sgcdm_app'

 // Connection to ArangoDB
db = new arangojs.Database({
    url: `http://${host}:${port}`,
    databaseName: databasename
});
db.useBasicAuth(username, password);

db.listCollections().then(function(res) {
    res.forEach((coll, i) => {
        console.log(`${i+1}. ${coll.name} (ID=${coll.id}, system=${coll.isSystem})`)
    });
}, function(err) {
    const res = err.response.body;
    console.log(`Error ${res.errorNum}: ${res.errorMessage} (HTTP ${res.code})`);
});
```

On success (database exists):

```
1. first (ID=264349479, system=false)
2. test (ID=264349463, system=false)
```

On error (unknown database):

```
Error 1228: database not found (HTTP 404)
```

*cross-post from [GitHub](https://github.com/arangodb/arangojs/issues/488)*